# Django/Django Rest How do I save user device to prevent tedious 2FA on every login?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hello I have been working with Django Rest Framework with JWT as authentication framework and I successfully made Two factor authentication Login based on Email OTP but one thing I want to improve is I want to improve login and save user's device so that repeated 2FA(Two factor Authentcation) can be minimized?

here is certain instance of code I did for sending otp on user email.

serializers.py

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = PasswordField()
```

views.py

```
class UserLoginView(generics.CreateWithMessageAPIView):
    """
    Use this end-point to get login for  user
    """
    message = _('Please check your email for 6 digit OTP code.')
    serializer_class = serializers.UserLoginSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        usecases.UserLoginWithOTPUseCase(self.request, serializer=serializer).execute()
```

usecases.py

```
class UserLoginWithOTPUseCase(CreateUseCase, OTPMixin):
    def __init__(self, request, serializer):
        self._request = request
        super().__init__(serializer)

    def execute(self):
        self._factory()

    def _factory(self):
        credentials = {
            'username': self._data['email'],
            'password': self._data['password']
        }
        self._user = authenticate(self._request, **credentials)
        if self._user is not None:
            """
            Sends email confirmation mail to the user's email
            :return: None
            """
            code = self._generate_totp(
                user=self._user,
                purpose='2FA',
                interval=180
            )

            EmailVerificationEmail(
                context={
                    'code': code,
                    'uuid': self._user.id
                }
            ).send(to=[self._user.email])
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied(
                {
                    'authentication_error': _('User name or password not matched')
                }
            )
```

I am confused how can I allow or save device to prevent repetitive 2FA.

Comment: You can use TokenAuthentication. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: I am Using Jwt at the moment

Comment: Are you using a library to create the otp or did you build it yourself?

Comment: It is PyOtp Library But I am handling Otp interval and other customization By myself

Comment: Not sure about the idea but save your own data on the users' browser and never delete it, check for the same data before 2fo. If the user clears the browser manually then you can repeat 2fo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### TLDR;

At a very high level: tokenize the OTP (exchange the `otp` for a `JWT`).

##### Explanation

A `JWT` is nothing more than a `JSON` **signed** payload with some standardized fields `exp` (expiration), `nbf` (not before), [etc...](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1). The signature (symmetric or asymmetric) assures integrity, authenticity, and non-repudiation (*eg the token has been issued by whom we think and has not been altered*).

Within a `JWT` payload you can put anything (keeping in mind that the value is not encrypted) including data required for your application logic. You can also exchange different `JWT` during different authentication steps.

#### Some examples

###### Deferred 2FA

- User gives you `<username, password>` if valid it receives a `type_1_jwt` if 2FA is enabled or else a `type_2_jwt`
- User gives you `<type_1_jwt, otp>` if both are valid it receives a `type_2_jwt`
- Your app accepts only `type_2_jwt` on all other endpoints

*Here you have the flexibility to request the OTP after initial user authentication (or even if a suspicious device is detected). If the OTP is required user is not required to insert the password again but also the password is never stored anywhere nor re-submitted in any future request. The security level is kept the same as `<username, password, otp>` simultaneous authentication*

###### Renew Token

- User authenticates and receives a `renew_jwt` (expires after a long period or never)
- User exchanges the `renew_jwt` for a `auth_jwt` (fast expiring)
- Your app accepts only `auth_jwt` on all other endpoints

*This solution allows for great flexibility if you want the authentication to be revoked or altered (altering roles). You can have `auth_jwt` that is used within your entire application but expires very fast, then you have a `renew_jwt` that has been already traded for proper authentication and can be used to automatically request an `auth_jwt`, this request will be met by the system only if certain criteria are met (for example authentication has not been revoked).*

#### Mixing all together

- User gives you `<username, password, otp>` it receives a `auth_jwt` (or a `renew_jwt`) and a `otp_jwt`.
- User gives you `<username, password, otp_jwt>`
- Your app accepts only `auth_jwt` on all other endpoints

*After the first authentication the user device receives an `otp_jwt` (that has an arbitrarily long duration) and can be stored on the device (cookies, appStorage, secureStorage, ...). This `otp_jwt` can be used in any future moment (together with username and password) to authenticate again.*

***Conceptually the `otp_jwt` token is a secure proof the user has successfully authenticated with an OTP in the past***

*Assuming the device can be considered reasonably safe, such strategy does not significantly increase the risk of unauthorized access. But keep in mind that you should always give an option to the user to `completely log out` eg to clear this token too.*

Answer (score 2):

What you can do here is whenever you create a JWT token and set it on user's device for a domain, along with it create a unique key (just an identifier for this device) and set it on the user's device as a cookie for that domain. (save this unique key and user's id map in a db)

Keep the expiry for this cookie different from that of the JWT and do not clean this cookie even if the user logs out. (let it self expire)

So even if the user logs out of the device or jwt expires, in the next login request you will still receive the device cookie you set (lets say you set it for a month).
when a login request comes and has a device cookie with it, you can check if this user id and device key is registered with you. If yes you know that this user has logged in with this device in the last one month and you can skip 2FA, else if no such combination exists you can prompt for 2FA.

Additionally lets say the user is logging in for the first time, in that case the device cookie will be missing in the request and you can safely prompt for 2FA.

you can play around with this device cookie's checks like you can also save the timestamp for when this key was created and increase the level of checks.